# MudBlazor select dropdown is transparent which it shouldn't be

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I am using [MudBlazor](https://mudblazor.com)'s multi select but when the drop-down menu opens it is transparent and you can see through to the underlying select which really doesn't look good.

This is what it looks like [MudSelect dropdown background is transparent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN6qx.png)

Here is my code:

```html
<MudGrid>
    <MudItem xs="12" md="12" lg="12">
        <MudSelect Label="US States" MultiSelection="true" @bind-Value="value" @bind-SelectedValues="options">
            @foreach (var state in states)
            {
                <MudSelectItem Value="@state">@state</MudSelectItem>
            }
        </MudSelect>
    </MudItem>
    <MudItem xs="12" md="12" lg="12">
        <MudText>MudSelect.Value: "@value"</MudText>        
    </MudItem>
</MudGrid>
```

What am I missing here? I looked at the documentation and the examples but did not find a clue why it works with their examples but not for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Adding `<MudThemeProvider/>` to MainLayout.razor fixed the problem. It looks alright now.

[MudSelect with open dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2QHB.png)